# javascript array indexOf not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

trying to build a html minesweeper game im a pretty much beginner and im trying to get a onclick to check if that box is equal to the value of a bomb spot

javascript i use to fill my "table" element ( with the id of "grid") giving each box/td an id 0-99

```
var gameBox = "";
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {

gameBox += "<tr>";
for ( var j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ ) {
    var idValue = i * 10 + j;
    gameBox += "<td class = 'box' id = '" + idValue + "' onclick = 'process(this);' ></td>";
}
gameBox += "</tr>";
}
document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = gameBox;
```

heres the bomb array intializer giving it a length of 10

```
var bomb = [];

for ( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
bomb[i] = 0;
}
```

after user clicks start button (heres the html:)

```
            <input type="button" class="MtopSmall" value="start!" name = "startButton" onclick = "start();" >
```

they trigger the start function which assigns 10 different random numbers 0-99

```
function start() {

for ( var i in bomb ) {

    var number = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );
        if( bomb.indexOf(number) >= 0 ){
            reassign(i);
        } else {
            bomb[i] = number;
        }   
    }

console.log(bomb);
}

function reassign(i) {

var number = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );
    if( bomb.indexOf(number) >=0)
    {
            reassign(i);
        } else {
            bomb[i] = number;
        }       
}
```

then when they click a box (td) it triggers the process function

```
function process(clicked) {
//change box look
clicked.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
clicked.style.border = "1px solid black"; 
bombCheck(clicked);
}
```

which triggers the bombCheck()

```
bombCheck(event)
var boxNum = event.id;
function bombCheck(event) {
if ( bomb.indexOf(boxNum) >=0 ) {
    event.innerHTML = "B";
     alert("you clicked a bomb");
    }
}
```

the problem is the final indexof (the one in bombcheck) always returns -1 weather or not its a bomb (and i check which r bombs with console.log) as you can see i used a similar indexOf check earlier in the same script and it works just fine plz help me

Comment: You seem to be treating   string as a number.. check answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of this line

```
var boxNum = event.id; //this returns a STRING of the id attribute
```

Then you later treat use it as a number.

Instead of that line use this

```
var boxNum = parseInt(event.id); //this will return a NUMBER which you can use
```

Comment: thanks i knew about parseInt didnt know .id returned i number

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Best of luck with the game :)

Comment: You probably shouldn't use numeric IDs to begin with. They weren't allowed in HTML4, and some browsers may not like them.

Comment: @Barmar atm i find numeric id's the most sensible for a loop especially since im using multiple loops (as you can see in my code) but if you have a good suggetion im all ears

Comment: Use IDs like `box1`, `box2`, etc. Then `var boxNum = parseInt(event.id.substr(3), 10);`

Comment: @Barmar thnx but atm i will skip it b/c it will comlicate things quite a bit but i will keep it in mind

Comment: and im using shiftedit.net atm and it gives me an error "missing radix parameter" next to the line "var boxNum = parseInt(event.id);" its not rlly bothering me b/c code is working but if any1 has something to say on that it might help

Comment: `parseInt(event.id, 10)`  or in this cause you could just use `boxNum = +event.id;`

Comment: nope i dont want += as a use it all over the place (i gotta check surrounding squares as well) and i didnt understand the "parseInt(event.id, 10)" but as i said it isnt rlly of much importance 2 me b/c its running pretty smoothly at this point